# COleDateTime adding an hour when constructed with time_t

Tags: c++, systemtime, coledatetime

I have a  `struct tm` object that is converted to UNIX time_t using `mktime`, that when passed into the constructor of `COleDateTime` seems to be adding an hour to account for daylight savings (UK time), even though the documentation for `COleDateTime` suggests that it ignores DST.

If I create my time with `SYSTEMTIME` and pass that object to `COleDateTime` the problem disappears. Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? This is from legacy code so changing everything to `SYSTEMTIME` may not be a solution.

Here is my example code:

```
timeinfo.tm_year = 2018 - 1900;
timeinfo.tm_mon = 6 - 1;
timeinfo.tm_mday = 1;
timeinfo.tm_isdst = 0;
timeinfo.tm_hour = 10;
timeinfo.tm_min = 30;
timeinfo.tm_sec = 40;

auto unix = mktime( &timeinfo );
printf("UNIX time %lld\n", unix);
COleDateTime date(unix);
printf("COleDateTime: %f\n", date.m_dt);
CString res = date.Format();
printf("Formatted: %ls\n", res.GetString());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered my own question:

`COleDateTime` `time_t` constructor uses `CTime` internally which, regardless of what the documentation for `COleDateTime` says, *does* take into account the environment variables for locale and timezone.